# Python 3.6 - formatting problem (+ other niggles)

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

## Part A - blank lines

I'm currently working my way through Kyran Dale's Data Visualization with Python and JavaScript. From example 3.1, I have this:

```
nobel_winners = [
{'name'       : 'Albert Einstein',
 'nationality': 'German', 
 'sex'        : 'male',
 'category'   : 'Physics',
 'year'       : 1921},
{'name'       : 'Paul Dirac',
 'nationality': 'British', 
 'sex'        : 'male',
 'category'   : 'Physics', 
 'year'       : 1933},
{'name'       : 'Marie Curie',
 'nationality': 'Polish', 
 'sex'        : 'female',
 'category'   : 'Chemistry', 
 'year'       : 1911}
]

cols = nobel_winners[0].keys()
# cols.sort() # <<== this produces an error - see below

with open('./nobel_winners.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')

    for o in nobel_winners:
        row = [str(o[col]) for col in cols]
        f.write(','.join(row) + '\n')

with open('./nobel_winners.csv') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line),
```

Now, the resulting file (noble_winners.csv) is like this:

```
name,nationality,sex,category,year
Albert Einstein,German,male,Physics,1921
Paul Dirac,British,male,Physics,1933
Marie Curie,Polish,female,Chemistry,1911
```

which is fine, **BUT**, when I do the printout (last 3 lines of code), I get this:

```
[pol@UNKNOWN example_3.1]$ python example3.1.py 
name,nationality,sex,category,year

Albert Einstein,German,male,Physics,1921

Paul Dirac,British,male,Physics,1933

Marie Curie,Polish,female,Chemistry,1911

[pol@UNKNOWN example_3.1]$
```

i.e. there are spaces between each line (which I don't want!). The author **specifically** says about the comma at the very end here (last line of code) **print(line),** "Adding a comma after the print function call inhibits the addtion of an unnecessary newline.".

Obviously, it does not. If I remove the comma, I obtain the same result, i.e. spaces in my printout.

I would like to know:

1. how to get a "clean" printout - i.e. no blank lines, and
2. some insight into what the author was trying to do - what is this comma "trick" supposed to be doing? How is it supposed to work?

## Part B - smaller point, but curious all the same.

If I uncomment the cols.sort() line, I get this:

[pol@UNKNOWN example_3.1]$ python example3.1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example3.1.py", line 20, in 
    cols.sort() # <<== this produces an error - see below
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'sort'

Now, I don't even understand what the author is getting at here

1. why is he trying to use a method that doesn't exist?
2. even it it did work, what's the point - he's merely going to have the column headers out of sync with his data?

Any explanation(s) gratefully received.

Comment: The trailing comma on `print` is for Python 2.x, in Python 3.x it won't do anything useful as `print` is now a function (which takes an `end` parameter for similar purposes). `dict.keys` used to produce a list, which *does* have a `.sort` method. Long story short: this code isn't written for Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for that - but why should I have to put in **anything** for the end of the line - why can't it just print out the file "as is" with the newline character being considered both part of and the end of a given line? Real pain about Python2/3 - the author **specifically** said that he was going to use 3!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of the question were not explained IMO:

> Now, I don't even understand what the author is getting at here
>
> 1. why is he trying to use a method that doesn't exist?
> 2. even it it did work, what's the point - he's merely going to have the column headers out of sync with his data?

---

Answer 1:

```
cols = nobel_winners[0].keys()
# cols.sort() # <<== this produces an error - see below
```

In Python 3, the `.keys()` does not produce a list of keys. It returns a "view", i.e. an object that changes dynamically with the dict. This makes it read-only (it supports iteration and membership test). Sorting it not possible.

In order to process dictionary keys, make a "snapshot" of the view, i.e. a copy in the form a list, or a tuple, or a set depending on your needs. For example:

```
keys = list(somedict.keys())
```

The resulting `keys` data are no longer connected with the original dict.

The `sorted` method mentioned in @stackels answer is fine too. It also makes a copy.

The same holds for dict values.

---

Answer2:

It is not fully clear, why the author prefers the sorted order, but he definitely needs to set some order of the columns, because the order of data in a regular dict is not defined. So he sets the column order and uses the same order for the heading and for all data lines. So they cannot get out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

This both sounds like the author used a different Python version for the scripts. I would recommend the following two code snippets in Python 3:

1. `print(line, end="")` removes the newline suffix and
2. `sorted(cols)` or even `sorted(nobel_winners[0])` because it automatically uses the dict keys. Else you'd have to use `sorted(nobel_winners[0].values())`.

Comment: Thanks for that - but **what's the point** in sorting the cols? Won't that make your column headers out of sync with your data?

Comment: Not in this case, since he sorts the columns and then does both, use the keys as the header line and then write each value in the same order: `[str(o[col]) for col in cols]`

Comment: Thanks for that - but why should I have to put in anything for the end of the line - why can't it just print out the file "as is" with the newline character being considered both part of and the end of a given line? Real pain about Python2/3 - the author specifically said that he was going to use 3! p.s. did you forget something in your previous comment? I can now see that the sorting does not affect the data - if you sort "cols" - the lot gets sorted!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The `sorted()` function should return a copy of the object. If you want to use `cols` then use `cols = sorted(nobel_winners[0])` instead.